# One ViewModel for multiple views in wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working on a wpf project with mvvm pattern, I have such a scenario: My window is seperated into two parts, the first part is simple, only a textbox for users to input keywords and a button for searching with keyword. The second part is user control, by default, it's a advanced search user control, users can select different selections, such as categories, authors, each of the selection support multiple selection. After user setting the filter in the advanced search user control, click search button in the first part to search. After the searching results return, replace the advanced search user control with a result list user control.

Should I create a viewmodel contains result collection, advanced search options and used for the main window and the two user controls? Or is there any more appropriate solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In my opinion, not required two area for search functionality. Make one space for search and other for showing the search result. This will give a nice UI experience for users. Eg: In Visual Studio find options box will show only search textbox by default. While click more option will shows other functionalities too. To show search results in UI, not required any additional ViewModel. You can manage this by declaring a property to store search results and bind this property to your UI Element

Comment: Since the space is limit, so I have to use user control in the second part. Thanks

Comment: Li.. You always welcome. Please Upvote the comment if useful